# Android Studio showing errors on restart

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I was working fine. My p.c powered off due to light.  When I start again my android studio, there came a lot of errors in my all java files. How can I solve them?

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private boolean detectEnabled;
    private TextView textViewDetectState;
    private Button buttonToggleDetect;
    private Button buttonExit;
    FlashLight flashLight;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textViewDetectState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDetectState);

        buttonToggleDetect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDetectToggle);
        buttonToggleDetect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setDetectEnabled(!detectEnabled);
            }
        });

        buttonExit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonExit);
        buttonExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , FlashLight.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void setDetectEnabled(boolean enable) {
        detectEnabled = enable;

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallDetectService.class);
        if (enable) {
            // start detect service
            startService(intent);
            buttonToggleDetect.setText("Turn off");
            textViewDetectState.setText("Detecting");
        }
        else {
            // stop detect service
            stopService(intent);
            buttonToggleDetect.setText("Turn on");
            textViewDetectState.setText("Not detecting");
        }
    }

}
```

Here is a screenshot of my issue:

[image: Code screenshot]

Comment: how should we know? we can just randomly guess everywhere.

Comment: This question is probably going to be downvoted for lack of detail. You need to share the specifics of the errors — at least the first few of them.

Comment: sir i had upload pic plz check it

Comment: Did my answer work? Feel free to ask me any questions if it didn't. If it did, make sure to mark it best answer! :)

Comment: Some time this occurs when compileSdkVersion,
    buildToolsVersion and your support library version has different versions.
Recently I had same problem and that was because I was messed up with the different versions. And other than that you can just invalidate/cache restart

Answer (score 0):

Because we don't have enough information, we can't tell you. This has happened to me before though, so I can give you a few tips:

1. Just wait until the gradle build is done, often times there are random errors which resolve themselves after a few minutes. This especially happens with resources that you are getting based on an id, R from `R.id` shows as an error until the gradle build is finished
2. Clean your project. **Build->Clean Project**
3. Rebuild Project. **Build->Rebuild Project**
4. Restart Android Studio
5. Restart Computer

Honestly, we can't give you more information than that until we get more details. Chances are it's number 1 that is the problem, so just wait.

```
{Rich}
```

Comment: Sir i have created new project. But there have also errors.

Comment: @ShahryarAziz No, don't create a new project. Just open android studio and wait. Trust me, don't mess with it until it stops saying `Gradle Build Running` If the Gradle Build is finished and the issue persists, then do steps 2 - 5. Don't just build a new project.

Comment: sir i had upload pic plz check it

Comment: @ShahryarAziz Okay, I saw your picture and the code has no actual errors. It is just what I thought. Just leave the screen open for some time and it will go away. It is still loading (Gradle still running). Don't worry, it's not your fault, it's either your computer or android-studio's fault.

Comment: @ShahryarAziz Don't keep messing with it, that will just go slower. Just let it load.

Answer (score 0):

**Build**--> Clean Project

**Build**-> Rebuild Project

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to <kbd>File</kbd>
2. Then <kbd>Invalidate Cache/ Restart</kbd>
3. After that hit <kbd>Invalidate and Restart</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

It's not a pleasant moment when your computer suddenly turns off and corrupting your project files. Sadly, when using Windows, you have a small hope that your files integrity are still intact when the Windows suddenly turn off due to power failure or having a friendly [BSOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death). I've experienced project error twice in a month because of it. Windows can't be counted for reliability, tried Linux instead.

To prevent another files error (or should I says, corrupted files?), you should always back up your project. Use a Version control systems (VCS) like **git**. Then copy/clone your project to USB flash drive. Or you can use a free private repository for git:

1. [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)
2. [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-com/)

Always, always, always backup.

Answer (score -1):

Build->Clean Project. This will solve your problem.